# Laravel: like won't work for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

[image]

Why this query is not working. Executing same thing in sql database returns me this one result that's in image. so doing q `select * from kolejka where data like '2017-04-08%'` in mysql works. In php artisan tinker it won't work and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `all()` first, you get all data and then work with it. `like` won't work here. So, do this instead:

```
\App\Kolejka::where('data', 'like', '2017-04-08%')->get();
```

If you just want to get records by date, just use `whereDate()`:

```
\App\Kolejka::whereDate('data', Carbon\Carbon::parse('2017-04-08'))->get();
```